# Handling Multiple Organization with MVC.Net Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and trying to build a Website with Multi Organization. I am using the MVC.Net with inbuilt role provider for roles management.

Now I am stuck where I need to implement the users can be in roles of multiple organization. I use the aspnet_user table. roles table as the user table and I have another table called "Organization" which contains the organization Id.

How can Handle this case. Do I need add the Organization Id to the Aspnet Roles table or Do I need to create a new table. If I need to create new table can I use the Inbuilt roles with this new table.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, What structure are you looking for? are you looking for the organization to have the roles to be able to assign to users under the organization? or is the organization the actual role you are giving the user? you might want to go further into detail with your question, maybe even a hierarchy written out to show what you are looking for. It also would not hurt to show your models and controller.

Comment: I have AspNetRoles roles table and a table for OrganisationRole as "Organization Id, RoleId, UserId", I wonder how to map the roles to the OrganisationRole  table. The user may be in multiple roles. Hope I am clear now